# Inject nuxt.config.js configuration into globally registered component using custom built Nuxt module

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs, nuxt.config.js

So this question might be quite complicated, but I'll try to explain it as clear as I can.

I am currently in the process of creating a Nuxt Module. If you're familiar with creating them you know it's possible to configure it in your `nuxt.config.js`. Which I have done right here:

```
components: {
    modules: ['carousel', 'filter', 'post-loop', 'gform'],
    gform: {
         title: true
    }
},
```

I have an array of modules that I would like to globally register. I have done so using the following configuration:

(index.js)

```
const path = require('path');

export default function ClassName(moduleOptions) {

    const options = Object.assign({}, this.options.components, moduleOptions);
    const availableModules = ['carousel', 'filter', 'gform', 'post-loop'];
    const unknownModules = options.modules.filter(mod => !availableModules.includes(mod));

    if(!options.modules) {
        throw new Error('ERROR: Please check the ReadMe, you need to include a modules array specifying what modules you want to enable');
    }

    if(unknownModules.length > 0) {
        throw new Error(`ERROR: The following modules do not exist in the @blueelevation/components module: ${unknownModules}`);
    }

    this.addPlugin({
        src: path.resolve(__dirname, './plugin/plugin.js'),
        options: options
    })

    const cssFilesToLoad = ['carousel.css'];

    cssFilesToLoad.forEach(file => this.options.css.push(path.resolve(__dirname, `dist/css/${file}`)));

    this.addPlugin({
        src: path.resolve(__dirname, './plugin/eventbus.js'),
    })
}
```

The important part to focus on is the `plugin.js` in which I register the components globally in the Nuxt instance:

```
import Vue from 'vue';

/**
 * If the module array contains carousel, we register it as a global component.
 */
<% if(options.modules.includes('carousel')) { %>
    import Carousel from '@blueelevation/components/components/Carousel/Carousel.vue';
    Vue.component('Carousel', Carousel);
<% } %>

/**
 * If the module array contains post-loop, we register it as a global component.
 */
<% if(options.modules.includes('post-loop')) { %>
    import PostLoop from '@blueelevation/components/components/PostLoop/PostLoop.vue';
    Vue.component('pwa-post-loop', PostLoop);
<% } %>

/**
 * If the module array contains filter, we register it as a global component.
 */
<% if(options.modules.includes('filter')) { %>
    import Filter from '@blueelevation/components/components/Filter/Filter.vue';
    import FilterHeading from '@blueelevation/components/components/Filter/FilterHeading.vue';
    Vue.component('pwa-filter', Filter);
    Vue.component('pwa-filter-heading', FilterHeading);
<% } %>

/**
 * If the module array contains gform, we register it as a global component.
 */
<% if(options.modules.includes('gform')) { %>
    import GForm from '@blueelevation/components/components/GForm/GForm.vue';
    Vue.component('pwa-gform', GForm);
<% } %>
```

As you can see I register the component globally in case it is specified in the array. The part where I'm currently stuck on is that I have a `gform.title` property in my `nuxt.config.js`. How do I pass this `Boolean` to the globally registered GForm component? So I can conditionally render the title in case it's `true`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my own question. If somebody every wonders how to do it, you can inject something into your component(s) by doing the following in `plugin.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Carousel from '@blueelevation/components/components/Carousel/Carousel.vue';
import PostLoop from '@blueelevation/components/components/PostLoop/PostLoop.vue';
import Filter from '@blueelevation/components/components/Filter/Filter.vue';
import FilterHeading from '@blueelevation/components/components/Filter/FilterHeading.vue';
import GForm from '@blueelevation/components/components/GForm/GForm.vue';

    export default(context, inject) => {
    /**
     * If the module array contains carousel, we register it as a global component.
     */
    <% if(options.modules.includes('carousel')) { %>
        Vue.component('Carousel', Carousel);
    <% } %>

    /**
     * If the module array contains post-loop, we register it as a global component.
     */
    <% if(options.modules.includes('post-loop')) { %>
        Vue.component('pwa-post-loop', PostLoop);
    <% } %>

    /**
     * If the module array contains filter, we register it as a global component.
     */
    <% if(options.modules.includes('filter')) { %>
        Vue.component('pwa-filter', Filter);
        Vue.component('pwa-filter-heading', FilterHeading);
    <% } %>

    /**
     * If the module array contains gform, we register it as a global component.
     */
    <% if(options.modules.includes('gform')) { %>
        Vue.component('pwa-gform', GForm);
        inject('GForm', {config: <%= serialize(options.gform) %> });
    <% } %>
}
```

Note the `inject()` function underneath the global registration of the gform component. I inject `GForm` with a serialized object (`options.gform` as seen in the `nuxt.config.js`). Afterwards this `GForm` config will be available in the component through:

`this.$GForm.config`.

Hope this helps somebody in the future.

Comment: You can accept your own answered question, it's fine!

Comment: @kissu if only stackoverflow would let me do it immediately... had to wait 2 days and can accept it tomorrow...

Comment: Yep forgot this one!